# I am looking to implement Platinum UPnP in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c-2.0, upnp

I want to implement Platinum UPnP for my iPhone Project, but the SDK does not really provide the proper documentation to help.

I tried to follow the below line as per read me file -

- MacOSX, iOS:
  Open the XCode project file located @ Platinum/Build/Targets/universal-apple-macosx/Platinum.xcodeproj
  To include Platinum to your XCode projects, simply add the project file then add Platinum as a Target Dependency as well as libPlatinum.lib in Link Binaries.
  Alternatively, you can build the Platinum.Framework using the PlatinumFramework target and add it to your project.

But ended up with this error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory:
'/Users/ankit.nigam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PlatinumDemo-gahtotovpnfcvyddmpiwgntarctu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Platinum/Platinum'
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Any idea on how to use this framework in deploying UPnP feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out what was the problem with the - I was to add the Platinum.framework to link binary and add the framework to header search path.

Comment: hi are you able to integrate the Platinum SDK in iOS? Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

first u must build a release version Platinum.frmework(i386,86,64,armv7),must release version.

and then.pull it and Neptune.frmework in your project.

at last, this is a C++ framework, so you must change .m to .mm where you use is in your file.